# Почему в Python преобразование к bool работает именно так?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this work?

```
>>> bool('1==1')
True
>>> bool('1=1')
True
>>> 1 == 1
True
>>> 1=1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal
>>>
```

Comment: Какое преобразование к bool?  Вы одному числу присваиваете другое.

Comment: __Любая__ непустая строка при преобразовании в булеан даст True

Comment: @MaxU и даже ноль? `"0"`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, и bool(“0”) и bool(“False”) вернут True

Answer (score 7):

```
bool('1==1')
bool('1=1')
```

Строки `'1==1'` и `'1=1'` не пустые, поэтому True. Это просто строки, там может быть любой текст. Питон не интерпретирует их как-то по особенному. Можно там написать "привет, Мир!" и будет True.

```
1 == 1
```

Питон сравнивает два объекта. Они равны, поэтому True

```
1=1
```

Тут объект со значением 1 присваивается переменной с названием 1. Названия переменных не могут начинаться с цифры и тем более быть цифрой полностью. Поэтому появляется ошибка.